# Division of two values results in 0

Tags: go, floating-point, int, division

I'm trying to make a division of two variables, but when I want to print the result, the program prints out 0

the leadTime and endAmount are being correctly printed by te program, but the monthlyAmount is being printed as 0. Also if I remove the float64() around endAmount and leadTime it is being printed as 0

```
var leadTime int
if currentAge < 45 {
    leadTime  = 120
} else if currentAge > 45 && currentAge < 55 {
    leadTime = 90
} else if currentAge > 55 {
    leadTime = 60
}
endAmount, _ := strconv.Atoi(amountAsString)

monthlyAmount:= (float64(endAmount) / float64(leadTime)
fmt.Println("leadTime :", leadTime )
fmt.Println("Total amount:", endAmount)
fmt.Println("monthlyAmount:", monthlyAmount)
```

with the standardinput I'm testing with, the leadTime = 120 and the endAmount = 93735.00 so the monthlyAmount should be: 781.13

Comment: This code does not compile. Please provide a complete working example. There are missing variable declarations in the code and syntax errors. A link to a Go Playground would go a long way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your trying to convert floating string an int in

```
endAmount, _ := strconv.Atoi(amountAsString)
```

This will give an error, but you're just neglecting it. Use `strconv.ParseFloat(amountAsString, 64)` to solve your problem.

Check the playground [example](https://play.golang.org/p/s5QM-hqGGvi) to see the error and the working code

Comment: You're also neglecting the error in your solution :-)

Comment: Oh I have missed it, updated the example. Thanks @colminator